# Functional equivalent of decorator pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, haskell, f#, functional-programming, clojure

What is the functional programming equivalent of the decorator design pattern?

For example, how would you write [this particular example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#First_example_(window/scrolling_scenario)) in a functional style?

Comment: I find Haskell's monad transformers similar to the decorator pattern. I may be wrong though, as I don't have that much experience using/writing monad transformers.

Comment: I must admit I haven't quite arrived as Monads are concerned but I find a lot of similarities between the Decorator pattern and Monads.

Comment: Combinator libraries are what you are looking for. Try looking at the classic example of parser combinators.

Comment: There's not really a need for a decorator pattern because behaviors are naturally decoupled from objects. You can add data to your type via a tuple, record, list or really any kind of containing data type.

Answer (score 33):

In functional programming, you would wrap a given function in a new function.

To give a contrived Clojure example similar to the one quoted in your question:

My original drawing function:

```
(defn draw [& args]
  ; do some stuff 
  )
```

My function wrappers:

```
; Add horizontal scrollbar
(defn add-horizontal-scrollbar [draw-fn]
  (fn [& args]
    (draw-horizontal-scrollbar)
    (apply draw-fn args)))


; Add vertical scrollbar
(defn add-vertical-scrollbar [draw-fn]
  (fn [& args]
    (draw-vertical-scrollbar)
    (apply draw-fn args)))

; Add both scrollbars
(defn add-scrollbars [draw-fn]
  (add-vertical-scrollbar (add-horizontal-scrollbar draw-fn)))
```

These return a new function that can be used anywhere the original drawing function is used, but also draw the scrollbars.

Comment: See also `comp`: `(def add-scrollbars (comp add-vertical-scrollbar add-horizontal-scrollbar))`.

Answer (score 18):

Currying functional parameters / composition is the closest equivalent. However, it's a mistake to even ask this question, because patterns exist to compensate for weaknesses in the host language.

If C++/Java/C#/any other practically identical language had a decoration feature built into the language, you wouldn't think of it as a pattern. It just so happens that "patterns" are patterns for structuring systems in early-bound imperative objective-oriented languages, usually without autoboxing, and with relatively thin protocols for the root class.

Edit: Also a lot of these are studied as patterns in these languages because there's no obvious built in higher order functions, higher order typing, and the type systems are relatively useless. Clearly, that's not a universal problem with these languages, but at the time these patterns started to be codified those issues were present.

Comment: Patterns are idioms documented in a certain style. That the GoF patterns might fit "early-bound imperative objective-oriented languages" is neither here nor there. There are some collections of functional patterns, it would be nice if there were a lot more.

Comment: Yes, they're idioms because there's no direct linguistic support, and the language makes it non-trivial to do those things well. Hence, idioms for how to do them well.

Comment: Or how to do them at all. Like the State monad in purely functional languages.

Comment: Exactly so - as I say weaknesses in the host language. Although, in the case of Haskell's monad support, the level of language support is such that I wouldn't call using monads an idiom in that language, more just a feature.

Comment: @Marcin, indeed, but before introducing language support in the form of `do` notation, this was pretty much a pattern (I would still call it a functional pattern in some contexts). There are however certain advantages to Haskell that make this look less like a pattern (operator support, typeclasses and terse lambda notation).

Comment: Quite. No-one is arguing that functional programming languages are immune to needing patterns.

Comment: @Marcin: In the Pragmatic Studio on Clojure Rich Hickey said ' Patterns mean "I have run out of language."', which is a fitting quote for this discussion :-)

Comment: @Marcin Completely agree with your answer. In fact in a paper 'Arguments and Results' written twenty years back Noble mentioned about curried object. His definition of curried object is very close to that of a decorator.

Answer (score 11):

You can "decorate" functions by wrapping them inside other functions, typically using some form of higher order function to perform the wrapping.

Simple example in Clojure:

```
; define a collection with some missing (nil) values
(def nums [1 2 3 4 nil 6 7 nil 9])

; helper higher order function to "wrap" an existing function with an alternative implementation to be used when a certain predicate matches the value
(defn wrap-alternate-handler [pred alternate-f f]
  (fn [x] 
    (if (pred x) 
      (alternate-f x)
      (f x))))

; create a "decorated" increment function that handles nils differently
(def wrapped-inc 
  (wrap-alternate-handler nil? (constantly "Nil found!") inc))

(map wrapped-inc nums)
=> (2 3 4 5 "Nil found!" 7 8 "Nil found!" 10)
```

This technique is used extensively in functional libraries. A good example is [wrapping web request handlers using Ring middleware](http://clojuredocs.org/ring/ring.middleware.params/wrap-params) - the linked example wraps parameter handling for html request around any existing handler.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
class Window w where
    draw :: w -> IO ()
    description :: w -> String

data VerticalScrollingWindow w = VerticalScrollingWindow w

instance Window w => Window (VerticalScrollingWindow w) where
    draw (VerticalScrollingWindow w)
       = draw w >> drawVerticalScrollBar w  -- `drawVerticalScrollBar` defined elsewhere
    description (VerticalScrollingWindow w)
       = description w ++ ", including vertical scrollbars"
```

Comment: Note to the OP: these "decorators" (i.e. polymorphic data types for which instances of `Window` type class are defined as shown above) are indeed stackable. You can write smth. like `do { let { w = SimpleWindow; w1 = VerticalScrollingWindow w; w2 = BorderedWindow w1 }; draw w2; }`

Comment: Why a type class, instead of simply using `data Window = Window { draw :: IO (), description :: String }`?

Comment: this is haskell code, or? maybe state that somewhere, for beginners?

Answer (score 6):

In Haskell, this OO pattern translates pretty much directly, you only need a dictionary. Note that a direct translation is not actually a good idea. Trying to force a OO concept into Haskell is kind of backwords, but you asked for it so here it is.

**The Window Interface**

Haskell has classes, which has all the functionality of an Interface and then some. So we will use the following Haskell class:

```
class Window w where
  draw :: w -> IO ()
  description :: w -> String
```

**The Abstract WindowDecorator class**

This one is a bit more tricky since Haskell has no concept of inheritance. Usually we would not provide this type at all and let the decorators implement `Window` directly, but lets follow the example completely. In this example, a `WindowDecorator` is a window with a constructor taking a window, lets augment this with a function giving the decorated window.

```
class WindowDecorator w where
   decorate :: (Window a) => a -> w a
   unDecorate :: (Window a) => w a -> a
   drawDecorated :: w a -> IO ()
   drawDecorated = draw . unDecorate
   decoratedDescription :: w a -> String
   decoratedDescription = description . unDecorate

instance (WindowDecorator w) => Window w where
   draw = drawDecorated
   description = decoratedDescription
```

Note that we provide a default implementation of `Window`, it can be replaced, and all instances of `WindowDecorator` will be a `Window`.

**The decorators**

Making decorators can then be done as follows:

```
data VerticalScrollWindow w = VerticalScrollWindow w

instance WindowDecorator VerticalScrollWindow where
  decorate = VerticalScrollWindow
  unDecorate (VerticalScrollWindow w ) = w
  drawDecorated (VerticalScrollWindow w )  = verticalScrollDraw >> draw w

data HorizontalScrollWindow w = HorizontalScrollWindow w

instance WindowDecorator HorizontalScrollWindow where
  decorate = HorizontalScrollWindow
  unDecorate (HorizontalScrollWindow w .. ) = w
  drawDecorated (HorizontalScrollWindow w ..)  = horizontalScrollDraw >> draw w
```

**Finishing Up**

Finally we can define some windows:

```
data SimpleWindow = SimpleWindow ...

instance Window SimpleWindow where
   draw = simpleDraw
   description = simpleDescription

makeSimpleWindow :: SimpleWindow
makeSimpleWindow = ...

makeSimpleVertical = VerticalScrollWindow . makeSimpleWindow
makeSimpleHorizontal = HorizontalScrollWindow . makeSimpleWindow
makeSimpleBoth = VerticalScrollWindow . HorizontalScrollWindow . makeSimpleWindow
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first of all lets try to find all the main components of decorator pattern in respect to OOP. This pattern is basically used to decorate i.e add **additional features** to an existing **object**. This is the simplest possible definition of this pattern. Now if we try to find the same components that are there in this definition in the world of FP, we can say that **additional features = new functions** and object are not there in FP, rather FP has what you call **data or data structure in various forms**. So in FP terms this patterns becomes, adding additional functions for FP data structures or enhancing existing function with some additional features.

Answer (score 2):

The [Joy of Clojure](http://joyofclojure.com/) talks about this very issue in chapter 13.3, "A lack of design patterns". According to the JoC, the [`->`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/-%3E) and [`->>`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/-%3E) macros are somewhat analogous to the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I think the [C9 lecture series on advanced functional programming](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Dr-Ralf-Laemmel-Advanced-Functional-Programming-The-Expression-Problem) explains the problem really good.

Aside from this you can use just the same technique inside F# (it supports just the same OO mechanism) and in this special case I would do so.

I guess it's a matter of tast and the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using JSGI, a web server API for JavaScript:

```
function Log(app) {
    return function(request) {
         var response = app(request);
         console.log(request.headers.host, request.path, response.status);
         return response;
     };
 }

 var app = Logger(function(request) {
     return {
         status: 200,
         headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
         body: ["hello world"]
     };
  }
```

Compliant middleware can be stacked, of course (e.x. `Lint(Logger(ContentLength(app)))`)

Comment: Looks like high order function

Answer (score 0):

```
type Window = {Description: string}
type HorizontalScroll = {HPosition: int}
type VerticalScroll = {VPosition: int}
type Feature = 
    | HorizontalScroll of HorizontalScroll
    | VerticalScroll of VerticalScroll

let drawWithFeatures w (f: Feature) = 
    match f with
    | HorizontalScroll h ->  {Description= w.Description + "Horizontal"}
    | VerticalScroll v -> {Description= w.Description + "Vertical"} 

type FeatureTwo = Red of int| Blue of int | Green of int | Feature of Feature
let rec drawWithMoreFeatures (w: Window) (ft:FeatureTwo)=
        match ft with 
        | Red x     ->  {Description = w.Description + "Red"} 
        | Green x   ->  {Description = w.Description + "Green"} 
        | Blue x    ->  {Description = w.Description + "Blue"}
        | Feature f ->  drawWithFeatures w f

let window = {Description = "Window title"}
let horizontalBar =   HorizontalScroll {HPosition = 10}
let verticalBar =  VerticalScroll {VPosition = 20}

[Red 7; Green 3; Blue 2; Feature horizontalBar; Feature verticalBar] |> List.fold drawWithMoreFeatures window
```

## F# attempt

This is my attempt at creating something sensible in F# since you asked for many examples. I'm a little rusty so hopefully nobody will shame me :P. The decorator basically requires two parts, new behaviors and new data. New behaviors are exceedingly easy in functional languages as they are "just another function", since functions are inherently decoupled from objects. New data is actually similarly easy and there's several ways you can achieve this, the simplest being a tuple. You can see I've created a new datatype that is a superset of the previous, and I've called the existing function for that existing behavior. So we have our old data and old behavior still respected, but we also have new behavior and new data.