# Is there anything similar to Python function decorators in F# programming language?

Tags: python, f#, decorator

I am learning F# and have some experience with Python. I really like Python function decorators; I was just wondering if we have anything similar to it in F#?

Comment: See also [Functional equivalent of decorator pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064389/functional-equivalent-of-decorator-pattern).

Answer (score 10):

There is no syntactic sugar for function decorators in F#.

For types, you can use `StructuredFormatDisplay` attribute to customize printf contents. Here is an example from [F# 3.0 Sample Pack](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Format):

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplayAttribute("MyType is {Contents}")>]
type C(elems: int list) =
   member x.Contents = elems

let printfnSample() = 
    printfn "%A" (C [1..4])

// MyType is [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

For functions, you can easily express [Python's decorators](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) using function composition. For example, [this Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/739665/634025)

```python
def makebold(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return "<b>" + fn() + "</b>"
    return wrapped

def makeitalic(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"
    return wrapped

@makebold
@makeitalic
def hello():
    return "hello world"
```

can be translated to F# as follows

```ml
let makebold fn = 
    fun () -> "<b>" + fn() + "</b>"

let makeitalic fn =
    fun () -> "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"

let hello =
    let hello = fun () -> "hello world"
    (makebold << makeitalic) hello
```